# Javascript / Jquery - loading gif animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, overlay, gif

I am trying to use [loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) to show some sort of loading animation when a Jquery UI tab is clicked. Once a tab is clicked, it enters the function below just fine and performs the tasks in that loop, but it never displays the overlay. If I remove the `$("#WholeContainer").unmask()` line, then the overlay shows, but it only shows once the data is already loaded and displayed... not before like I woudl expect.

I have had similar issues with trying to load animated gifs for spinner.js, etc... what am I doing wrong here?

```
 $("a[title=\"ByOpsGroup\"]").click(function()
    {//  alert(tabCnt1);

    $("#WholeContainer").mask("Loading...");
        for (var i=1;i<tabCnt1;i++)
        { 
            getListOfRulesApplyingToGroup(i,"ui-id-"+i);
        }
    $("#WholeContainer").unmask();
    });
```

Comment: You'll have to give the mask time to show ... a common way would be to use `setTimeout()` with a short time period and move the `for` loop into its callback

Comment: I wish that were true, but it isn't... in several different tests, the mask doesnt show until the data is loaded. I noticed that the mouse cursor also 'hangs' once the link is clicked, until the data loads, so this may just be a browser / application issue.